# Arguments for main in cmdLine

Tags: c++, multithreading, ubuntu

`g++ -pthread threads.cpp` I'm compiling my program with that command and I don't know how should I specify some arguments given from the keyboard(file names).
`int main(int argc,const char argv[])` is the head of my main and `f1.txt` and `f2.txt` are the files I want to pass.
`./a.out f1.txt f2.txt` is what I've typed and the answer was a screen full of unreadable characters.How should I do this?

Comment: `for(int i=1,i<argc;i++) pthread_create(&threads[i],null,print,(void*)argv[i]);` seems like it's following that rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int main(int argc,const char argv[])` is not correct, this `int main(int argc, char** argv)` is correct.

Then `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` will be your file names.

Comment: As an explanation, the original version takes just one string, the correct version takes an array of strings.

Comment: did this.I got another screen of unreadable characters.since the command seems correct I suppose the mistake is somewhere in what I print

Answer (score 0):

You should have got a warning from the g++, regarding the second argument in main.